# How to use marquee progress bar on a form while waiting for Task to complete

Tags: vb.net

I have an app that it's classes in several places calls C++ dlls to perform some data calculations. To not have the main UI thread not display "Not Responding" on the applications title bar when performing the dll calculations, I put the call to the dll in a Task, then wait for it to finish, since all code after the dll processing must wait for it to finish. I'm trying to display a form with a marquee progress bar to display while the dll Task in running, and then after it completes, just close the form. But when I Show the form, the progress bar is not activated (displays but no green bars .. just a blank control).

How do you get this to work? It is a Windows Form desktop application using .Net 4.0. Here is the code:

```
Sub combos_2()

        Dim combos_condition_output As Integer

        ' finds combinations and stores in class 2D array
        combos_find2()

        // displays dialog for getting matches between sets of combinations
        combos_condition_output = combos_trim_input(3)

        If (combos_condition_output <> -1) Then

            ' Form with just a label and a marquee progress bar
            ' Want marquee progress bar active during Task 't'
            Dialog12_trim_info.Show()

            Application.DoEvents()

            Dim t As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()

                                                      ' calls dll to trim combinations
                                                      ' according to dialog input above
                                                      combos_trim(combos_condition_output)

                                                  End Sub)

            t.Wait()

            ' After Task completes just close form
            Dialog12_trim_info.Close()

            ' finds matches of combinations against history of numbers...calls dll
            combos_matches()

            MsgBox("Finished")

            ' outputs results to text file
            combos_output()

        Else

            MsgBox("Finished")

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Fairly basic, the UI thread in your program can do only one thing at a time.  It can move the progress bar *or* it can wait for the task to complete.  You must delete `t.Wait()`.  Somewhat likelier you'll get this right when you use BackgroundWorker.  Or use Async/Await so you can await the task.  Or use Task.ContinueWith, using another task that runs on the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I had to enable Visual Styles before loading the progress form:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles()
```

Then after the task call:

```
't.Wait()


 While (Not t.IsCompleted)

     Dialog12_trim_info.ProgressBar1.Refresh()

     Application.DoEvents()

     Thread.Sleep(50)

 End While

 Dialog12_trim_info.Close()
```